# Type.GetProperties different properties between Collection and ICollection

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I am try to build an expression tree and I have this code

```
 var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Foo");
 var property = Expression.Property(param, "Bar");
 var param2 = Expression.Parameter(property.Type.GetProperty("Item").PropertyType, "x");
```

Now, Bar is a Collection property of Foo and I declare it as

```
public Collection<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
```

I am able to get the Item property once I call the Type.GetProperty
[image]

The problem I'm facing now is that the Entity class is autogenerated and it is declared as

```
public ICollection<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
```

Once I call the Type.GetProperty on ICollection, the Item property is missing.
[image]

Is there a way to get that even when using Interface (e.g. ICollection) since I cannot change the type of the properties of the class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `ICollection<T>` have an `Item` property or indexer? No it doesn't, so it isn't "missing". That's like saying that my third arm that doesn't exist is missing. If you get properties of the property type then you're only going to get properties that that type has. If you want to get properties of the type of the object at run time then you need to get that object. The fact that you can assign an `ILIst` to a property of type `ICollection` doesn't mean that you always will, so you can't expect to access properties that are members of `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it now.

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(Collection<Bar>));
var param2 = Expression.Parameter(converted.Type.GetProperty("Item").PropertyType, "x");
```

I just need to convert the property type so I can access that property.